# Retrieve data from one to many relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

This is my model I want to retrieve all students with each attendances list when class = value and month = November

[image]

Comment: your image is not clear.can you put models code ?

Comment: class student
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}class Attendance
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string month{ get; set; }
     public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use Include() function of entity framework. In your attendance entity you need connection to the student for example in Attendance.cs:

```
public int StudentId { get; set; }
```

And in Student entity you have a collection of attendances:

Student.cs

```
ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
```

And in class connection to student:

```
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public Student Student { get; set; }
```

Now you have to add sets of these entities to your database context:

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("context")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

You can now load your entity with connected entities with:

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var result =  db.Classes.Where( (clas) => clas.Value == SomeValue)
    .Include( (clas) => clas.Student     
        .Include( (student) => student.Attendances
        .Where( (attendance) => attendance.Month == "November") )); 
}
```

Comment: exception error :The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: in the query : var result =  var resultStudent = db.Students.Where((student) => student.Cls_Id == ClassId)
                        .Include((student) => student.Attendances
                         .Where((attendance) => attendance.Month == Month));

Comment: Oh I have now noticed that class is some other entity. Could you post your whole database schema and clarify what do you want the query to return? Do you want to retrieve all students for a given class with their attendances in november?

Comment: yes i want to retrieve all students for a given class with their attendances in november

Comment: But how exactly is Student connected to Class?

Comment: public partial class Attendance
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Std_Id { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Class_Id { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }

Comment: there is navigation  property between  class  student  and  class  Class : one to  many  relationship

Comment: So in class there is a property connecting to student something like public int StudentId { get; set; } ?

Comment: can make condition inside .Include() ??